# Skipping the row if there are more than 2 fields are empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First, skip the row of data if the columns have more than 2 columns that are empty. After this step, the rows with more than 2 columns missing value will be filtered out.

Then, as some of the columns still have 1 or 2 columns are empty. So I will fill in the empty column with the mean value of that row.

I can run the second step with my code below, however, I am not sure how to filter out the rows with more than 2 columns missing value.

I have tried using `dropna` but it deleted all the columns of the table.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp

%matplotlib inline

# high technology exports percentage of manufatory exports
hightech_export = pd.read_csv('hightech_export_1.csv') 

#skip the row of data if the columns have more than 2 columns are empty
hightech_export.dropna(axis=1, how='any', thresh=2, subset=None, inplace=False)

# Fill in data with mean value. 
m = hightech_export.mean(axis=1)
for i, col in enumerate(hightech_export):
    hightech_export.iloc[:, i] = hightech_export.iloc[:, i].fillna(m)
```

My dataset:

Country Name    2001    2002    2003    2004

Philippines 71

Malta   62  58  60  58

Singapore   60          56

Malaysia    58  57      55

Ireland 47  41  34  34

Georgia 38  41  24  38

Costa Rica

Comment: You should clarify your question, but the solution is an IF statement

Comment: I just edit my question, is it clear now? And Is it necessary to use IF statement? I have tried using ''' df1.dropna(thresh=2) '''  but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `.isnull()` method for doing your first task.

Replace this:

```
hightech_export.dropna(axis=1, how='any', thresh=2, subset=None, inplace=False)
```

with:

```
hightech_export= hightech_export.loc[hightech_export.isnull().sum(axis=1)<=2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
hightech_export.dropna(thresh=2, inplace=True)
```

in place of the line of code

```
hightech_export.dropna(axis=1, how='any', thresh=2, subset=None, inplace=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this ...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1={'Name':['Tom',np.NaN,'Mary','Jane'],'Age':[20,np.NaN,40,30],'Pay':[np.NaN,np.NaN,20,25]}
data2={'Name':['Tom','Bob','Mary'],'Age':[40,30,20]}

df1=pd.DataFrame.from_records(data1)
```

Check the df

df1

```
    Age Name    Pay
0   20.0    Tom NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN
2   40.0    Mary    20.0
3   30.0    Jane    25.0
```

record with index 1 has 3 missing values...

Replace and make missing values None

```
df1 = df1.replace({pd.np.nan: None})
```

Now write function to count missing values per row.... and to create a list

```
def count_na(lst):
    missing = [n for n in lst if not n]
    return len(missing)

missing_data=[]
for index,n in df1.iterrows():
    missing_data.append(count_na(list(n)))
```

Use this list as a new Column in the Dataframe

```
df1['missing']=missing_data
```

df1 should look like this

```
Age     Name    Pay    missing
```

0   20      Tom     None    1
1   None    None    None    3
2   40      Mary    20      0
3   30     Jane     25      0

So filtering becomes easy....

```
# Now only take records with <2 missing
df1[df1.missing<2]
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to compare on a row basis the count of value and the number of columns of the dataframe. You can then just replace NaN with the avg of the dataframe.

Code could be:

```
result = df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis=1) >= (len(df.columns) - 2)].replace(
             np.nan, df.agg('mean'))
```

With your example data, it gives as expected:

```
  Country Name  2001   2002       2003  2004
1        Malta  62.0  58.00  60.000000  58.0
2    Singapore  60.0  49.25  39.333333  56.0
3     Malaysia  58.0  57.00  39.333333  55.0
4      Ireland  47.0  41.00  34.000000  34.0
5      Georgia  38.0  41.00  24.000000  38.0
```